# After UPS battery replacement (HP R/T 3000)

Tags: hp, electrical-power, ups, battery

has any one had experience with this UPS?

i have replaced the batteries but have't ran self test yet, if i run self test is there a risk of powering down the machines the UPS powers?

just wondering if i should run the self test out of hours or during office hours?

another issue i have is the battery capacity is showing 0% i imagine after the self test this fix's its self but just wanted to be sure.

[image]

any input would be helpful
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

After a battery replacement you will need to run a calibration and also set the battery replacement date.

This will simulate the UPS going onto battery power, at around 5% the UPS should go back onto mains to re-charge. Once that happens you should get the correct readings in your GUI.

There shouldn't be any risk to the system but with anything like this make sure you assess the risk.

Comment: +1 Just do it off-hours. Particularly if you didn't get HP batteries (which come with directions, so I'm thinking he got off-name batteries - this will also validate that the batteries will even work, I've seen plenty of cheap replacement batteries that plain don't work in UPSs).

Comment: turns out when i installed the batters one of the small connectors completing the circuit had came off, i removed the batteries and reseated the contact, This resolved the issue, once the battery self test ran it worked a treat, they went official HP battery's but they were from a reputable vendor, they done the trick we now have UPS uptime.

thanks for the help